# How to connect two points of the Board Shape with an angle of other than 45º?

Tags: pcb, altium

I'm drawing the Board Shape of my board and one of the corners the connection has an angle other than 45°.  Altium is not allowing me to make the connection, does anyone know how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: For more complex shapes it may be better to create the outline in another program, import the DXF outline onto a mechanical layer and use "define from selected objects".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear exactly what you mean by "has a different angle of 45°". Do you mean "has an angle **other than** 45°"? If so, while drawing the line press shift-space a few times until you get the "any angle" option. This will allow you to draw the line at any angle (not restricted to 45 degrees).

Comment: First of all, apologies for my English. Thanks for the answer, it worked.

Comment: @EduardoCardoso Glad to hear it!

Answer (score -1):

You Can set the Angle in Design> Rules > Routing Corner > Set the angle 
you can Set the angle you want other than 45 degree